# Do some animals have a notion of cooking?

Tags: zoology, ethology

Humans turned the concept of feeding themselves into a whole field in which they rearrange ingredients so as to obtain specific flavours and so on. It's more effort than just feeding ourselves.

Do some animals have a similar behaviour ? I guess at smaller scales of course, but did we already observe animals associate certain ingredients just for the propose of it tasting good or something like that?

Comment: This question has been asked before: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42422/do-any-animals-prepare-food